# wget download a URL with filter

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, wget

I want to download all jpg files of URL "www.link.com". However the jpg download links start with "dl.link.com".
When I use the following code, it does not download any file. I assume because the download links are different from the URL in the code. Any solution? Thanks.

```
wget -r -p -A .jpg" http://www.link.com
```

Comment: You didn't mention the OS you are running this on (Windows/XNIX). Please provide your OS and OS Version details.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Is there an example you could provide that I could test against?

Answer (score 0):

In the command line you provided:

```
wget -r -p -A .jpg" http://www.link.com
```

you have an unmatched double-quote-mark (") following `.jpg`

Perhaps you meant:

```
wget -r -p -A ".jpg" http://www.link.com
```

or

```
wget -r -p -A .jpg http://www.link.com
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually my typo! I tried all the combinations you mentioned. Unfortunately, still does not work!